# Is there a javascript mvc system officially endorsed by jQuery team?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Is there a JavaScript MVC system (such as backbone.js JavaScriptMVC) officially endorsed by jQuery team?

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Comment: you can find all of the jquery projects here: http://jquery.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I do not believe so. It is beyond the scope of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "officially endorsed", but from [JavaScript MVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/) page:

> JavaScriptMVC is an open-source framework containing the best ideas in jQuery development.